# Can't get around ImageResizer error: File may be corrupted, empty, or may contain a PNG image with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels

Tags: c#, imageresizer

Not sure what I'm missing.

Trying to take a jpg from a simple input[type=file] POST and scrub it into two versions (1800x1800) and (400x400).

Code:

```
stream.Position = 0;//probably only need one of these lines
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);//i've tried both to no avail
ImageJob job = new ImageJob(stream, origStream, 
    new Instructions("maxwidth=1800&maxheight=1800")).Build();
```

Throws:

```
File may be corrupted, empty, 
or may contain a PNG image with a single dimension greater than 65,535 pixels.
```

`stream` comes from `context.Request.InputStream` I'm just passing it through a method call. and the other is `MemoryStream origStream = new MemoryStream()` from a wrapped `using`

I've read through some of the docs and some of the other SO posts that reference this error. All of the ones that I found on SO reference using a plugin, I'm using no plugins.

My best guess is that I'm missing some configuration to get ImageResizer to work, but I haven't been able to find that yet.

PS I am able to save the file if I skip the image processing step, so the image stream is good, I just can't use ImageResizer to change it.

Comment: Is this on the first or second call? Do other jpeg files work? Can you show more code?

Comment: This is the first call. I haven't set up the second call yet because I can't get the first resize to work.

Comment: I can't get any jpg files to work.

Comment: I'm using the Windows shipped jpgs to test with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in the input stream.

`context.Request.InputStream`

should be:

`context.Request.Files[0].InputStream`

The `InputStream` hanging off of `Request` contains the entire body, form and all. NOT a valid image.